# How to bring Classic Text From Adobe Illustrator to Adobe Flash Professional?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, textfield, flash-cs4, adobe-illustrator

I am working on a game project with a graphic designer. I am the programmer/developer and she is drawing everything in illustrator. However, when I drag the assets, buttons, screens, etc into Flash Professional, they all appear in very bad quality, and in TLF text.

I am wasting tons of time changing each bit of text to classic, deleting the random extra return carriage, and then repositioning the textField. I must be doing something wrong because  the people at Adobe really cannot be that dumb to force developers to do this every time you move graphics from Illustrator to Flash Pro.

Comment: TLF text is pretty awful for the most part. Is the text in the textFields static?

Comment: no. they need to be textFields so they can have as3 instance names

Answer (score 1):

> I must be doing something wrong because the people at Adobe really cannot be that dumb to force developers to do this every time you move graphics from Illustrator to Flash Pro

Haha. Good joke. This is the tip of the iceberg when it comes to stupid things that Adobe software does.

In my role I do a lot of Flash banners, and the designers use Fireworks.

I've done 500+ banners since starting work and almost every single one has needed the text fields to be readjusted once they're imported. The line and letter spacing is never the same, the size doesn't translate correctly, etc.

If you don't actually need to the text to be editable, you could consider outlining it before you import it. This way, you'll have the same result when you copy and paste it. This may not be the best solution if you're using the same font in many areas, because the file size of the SWF will be noticeably higher.